# How to get the most trusted and accurate linux distro stats?

Tags: distributions, stat, statistics

I need the Linux distros usage statistics.

I need this data to make a more informed decision for our future technology choices.

However, I can't find the data. It seems that [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity) is a good place to start. But it only shows the trends based on visits to their sites:

> The counters are no longer displayed on the individual distributions pages, but all visits are logged. Only one hit per IP address per day is counted.

Though that might be a good indicator, it's not the true **usage** data. It's more related to the hype around the distros. I might run Debian, but visit their site and read more about Linux Mint.

Another option seemed to be [TechMint](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-distributions/). However, their data is also different from the DistroWatch. Here, we see that Ubuntu and Debian are at the top of the list (along Mint) but in DistroWatch they are at much lower ranks.

And [StatCounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/os-market-share) does not have data for Linux distros only. Or at least I can't find it.

Is there a formal, well-established place to give us Linux usage stats?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a formal, well-established place to give us Linux usage stats?

None.

The best so far has been https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/ but it's only tracking Linux gamers and only the top four distros.

Some individual distros keep track of how many users have them installed e.g. [Fedora](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/1172nvv/in_2023_fedora_sports_350_thousand_active/), but that's it.

Web trackers such as StatCounter simply cannot collect such stats because Linux distros normally do *not* send this information as part of the HTTP request.

Comment: Yup, and even for Fedora [the tracking is partial](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/distributions/1373407-fedora-planning-ahead-for-the-next-5-years/page4#post1374041).